# Android Thread Error Message

Tags: android, multithreading

```
package your.splash.namespace;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity{

protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime=1500;  //The timeout 
TextView tv;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.stext);

   Thread splashThread = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                int waited=0;

                      //the thread will stop if _active==false and bigger than _splashTime
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime))
                {
                    sleep(100);

                    if(_active)
                    {
                        waited +=100;
                    }
                }
            }catch(InterruptedException e)
            {

            }
            finally
            {
                tv.setText("how"); //when it is timeout, the text will change to this one
            }
        }


    };

    splashThread.start();
}

//When user press screen, it set _active to false to stop the thread
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
   if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
   {
       _active = false;
   }

   return true;
}
}
```

I just want to set the Text "how" to TextView when the thread is timeout. This program can run in the Eclipse. However, When the thread time out, an popup error message "Unfortunately, SplashScreen has stopped" show up and then the program exit(stop) after I press the OK button. what is wrong? How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

```
 tv.setText("how"); is in onon UI thread...
```

you can't do UI related work in other then UI thread...

```
finally
            {


runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       tv.setText("how");
    }
});

}
```